# ruby methods scope and DRY

Tags: ruby, methods, scope

```
  def ads
    @ads = @search.result.recent.completed.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).limit(10)
  end

  def events
    @events = @search.result.recent.completed.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).limit(10)
  end

  def pets
    @pets = @search.result.recent.completed.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).limit(10)
  end

  def companies
    @companies = @search.result.recent.completed.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).limit(10)
  end
```

how to refactor this code to some scope

Comment: it's not clear what you wish to accomplish. What's the concrete goal?

Comment: something like `@ads = @search.scope_name`

Comment: That is not clear, should @ads then equal 'city wide', 'country wide' or 'international'?  Or what is 'scope_name'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear what you really want to archive. Without knowing the context I would rewrite your code to something like this:

```
%w( ads events pets companies ).each do |name|
  class_eval <<-END_OF_RUBY, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1

    def #{name}
      @#{name} = search
    end

  ENF_OF_RUBY
end

private 
  def search
    @search.result.recent.completed.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 10).limit(10)
  end
```